# Offset with sum Excel

Tags: excel, sum, offset

I have a workbook with Columns A1:A9 - I1:I9 containing numbers. Column J1-J9 shows the values of A1-I1. What I would like to do is show the sum of A1:A9 in J1 and follow that method down. Here is my offset formula:

```
=OFFSET($A$1:1,0,ROW(A1)-1,1,1)
```

Is there a way to add a `SUM` to this?

Comment: Can you mock up the data and expected output? it is not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: A      B      C     D
1      1
 
2
3

Comment: Not in the comments.  [Edit] your original post to include.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as  cell J1 ```=sum(A1:I1)```  ??

Comment: @Brian `show the sum of A1:A9 in J1` not A1:I1 in J1

Comment: First of all, you should read your post 10 times and think about using proper terms. I can't understand ANYTHING that you wrote. There is no such thing as Column A1:A9, it's a range. Then you write Column J1-J9, now I don't know if it's actually a range J1:J9 or you subtract...? Again "shows the values of A1-I1, is that A1:I1 or A1 minus I1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can understand, you want to sum A1:A9 in J1 and B1:B9 in J2 and so on...

If that is correct, put this in J1:

```
=SUM(INDEX($A$1:$I$9,0,ROW(A1)))
```

and drag down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

Note if there is no data below then one can use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:I,0,ROW(A1)))
```

Comment: Are you using Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: @ThisGuyUsesPowershell see edit.  I was able to shorten the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Scott is correct, here is another way:

`=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,ROW())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,ROW())))`

Copy and paste down the column.

Comment: As an FYI:  `INDIRECT`,`ADDRESS`, and `OFFSET` are all Volatile functions.  That means it will recalc every time Excel recalcs even if the data to which it refers did not change.  NonVolatile functions only recalc if the data to which it refers changes.  Where a handful of these will not make a difference it is one reason for slow workbooks and should be used sparingly.